# vBulletin plugin with cURL

Tags: php, curl, vbulletin

I've tried the following guide for including external files in a template using [this manual](https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/templates_externalfiles).

I've created a plugin with this code below and included it in a template using the `$includedphp` variable:

```
ob_start();
include('http://foo.bar.com/external.php');
$includedphp = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Afterwards I've found out that `include()` is disabled in the server configuration. My other option is to use `cURL` which is enabled:

```
$curl = curl_init( "http://foo.bar.com/external.php" );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
$includedphp = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
```

It's not working. It just prints blank in my template. Hooks used: `"global_start"`. vBulletin version: 3.8.

Comment: Did you try asking at the vB forums?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use curl as a replacement of include.
How could include is disabled?
I see that you use http:// on your include code, what if you use non-http?

```
include(DIR.'/external.php');
```

Note: DIR constant contains vbulletin forum installation root on vb4, so i'm not sure for vb3.